# MySQL Tree-Hierarchy query?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, recursion

I need to get all the child nodes of a parent ?

My table is say as follows

```
id

parent_id
```

and say data is

```
id   parent_id

1     -1

2      1

3     -1

4      2

5      4
```

I want a query which will return all child for a given id

For example if I pass 1 it will return 2, 4, 5

Comment: Is it multiple levels or just one level ? parent->chield or great-parent -> parent -> child?

Comment: You can't do it with a single query then (not in mysql). You will need a function. See it here: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: Well, you could, just not with this data structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @input = 1;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lvl SEPARATOR ',') children FROM (
SELECT @q := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM tbl
WHERE parent_id IN (@q)) AS lvl FROM tbl
JOIN
(SELECT @q := @input) tbl
WHERE parent_id IN (@q)) t;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8971d/1) for the query.